# Do I have to create Jira ticket for each new project under group in Maven Central

Tags: maven, sonatype, maven-central

I have project group in **Maven Central** and one library project in it.

What should I do if I'd like to publish new project?
Should I create new ticket for each project or can just upload and stage it?

Comment: Usually you get a are which contains your domain which you are responsible for. If your new project is within this domain you don't need a new ticket you can just stage that.

Comment: @khmarbaise why not to post this as answer?
It's seems an answer for me, so I can chose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you get a are which contains your domain which you are responsible for. If your new project is within this domain you don't need a new ticket you can just stage that.